# Does Java fail to deduce the generic type parameter when using the ternary operator (`?`)?

Tags: java, generics

Why is the compiler able to determine the generic type parameter for an
assignment, but not for the ternary operator (`?`)?

I have a question regarding the compiler being able to deduce the generic type
parameter in case of a "direct" assignment but failing in case of the ternary
operator (`?`). My examples uses Guava's `Optional` class, to make my point, but
I think the underlying issue is generic and not restricted to `Optional`.

`Optional` has a generic function `absent()`:

```
public static <T> Optional<T> absent();
```

and I can assign an `Optional<T>` to an `Optional<Double>`:

```
// no compiler error
final Optional<Double> o1 = Optional.absent();
```

How does the compiler realize, that `T` should be `Double` in this case. Because
when using the ternary operator (`?`), I need to tell the compiler specifically
to us `Integer` as the generic parameter

```
// Type mismatch: cannot convert from Optional<capture#1-of ? extends Object> to Optional<Integer>
final Optional<Integer> o2 = true
    ? Optional.of(42)
    : Optional.<Integer>absent();
```

otherwise I get the following error

> Type mismatch: cannot convert from `Optional<capture#1-of ? extends Object>` to `Optional<Integer>`

Why is there a difference between a "direct" assignement and using the ternary
operator? Or is there something else I am missing?

Comment: what is the return type of `of` method ?

Comment: Same as `absent()`: `public static <T> Optional<T> of(T reference);`

Comment: Which version of javac are you compiling this with?

Comment: Java version is Java 1.7.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because of type inference rules, it appears the ternary expression does not infer the type parameter from the return type.  The type of the ternary expression depends on the types of its operands. But one of the operands has undetermined type parameter (`Optional.absent()`). At that point the ternary expression still does not have a type, so it cannot influence the type parameter.

You can also look into this [bug report](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6721089) for more information. You can look into the [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.7) .

> The type of the conditional expression is the result of applying capture conversion (??5.1.10) to lub(T1, T2)

Here what the [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.8) says :

> If the method result occurs in a context where it will be subject to assignment conversion to a type S, then let R be the declared result type of the method, and let R' = R[T1 = B(T1) ... Tn = B(Tn)] where B(Ti) is the type inferred for Ti in the previous section, or Ti if no type was inferred.

Answer (score 5):

The Problem is that the result of the ternery Operator is assigned to o2.
The compiler can't deduce the type across multiple operations.

Basically I think you write the short form of:

```
Optional<?> tmp = true ? Optional.of(42): Optional.absent();
final Optional<Integer> o2 = tmp;
```

The conversion of the second line is the problem.