# Why does casting a generic return type to another generic type work?

Tags: generics, java-8

I was looking at another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64839117/redundant-cast-to-java-lang-object-warning-for-necessary-cast) and found it interesting that i got a new question.

```
public class Test {
    public static <T> void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(String
                .valueOf(true ? 'a'
                        : true ? 'b'
                        : true ? 'c'
                        : (T)fail())); // If we remove the cast to T, compilation will fail
    }

    public static <R> R fail() {
        throw null;
    }
}
```

The compilation will fail if we remove the cast to R as highlighted in the comment. Why does it happen like that? Casting it to Object also works.

When i looked into the JLS about [Poly expressions in Conditional expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25) (*Table 15.25-E. Conditional expression type (Reference 3rd operand, Part III)*) it says that `lub(Character, Object)` will be taken in this case which would be `Object` (?)

Edit: Modifying the type variable to T to establish that i know the type parameters, though having similar names, are different in the two methods.

Comment: Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17522790/does-java-fail-to-deduce-the-generic-type-parameter-when-using-the-ternary-opera).  I think it will help.  If you just had the `fail()` method and no ternary, it would have worked.

Comment: But that answer is still not describing this case here. That is talking about a ternary operator having the second and third part both being a generic type and hence the type couldn't be inferred by the compiler. Once a type hint is added to one of the parts, it compiles fine. Also the assignment is also generic`Optonal<Integer>` but in my case the formal argument type is not generic.

Comment: @WJS I don’t think that an answer for Java 7 is suitable to answer any type inference question about a later version.

Comment: @Holger you're right of course.  I hadn't noticed the 1.7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not “casting a generic return type to another generic type”. When a method declares a type variable, the immediate caller of the method decides what to substitute for the type parameter. When no bound has been specified for the type parameter, any reference type can be used. We could invoke `Test.<Object>fail()`, or `Test.<Character>fail()`, or even `Test.<Thread>fail()`. When we don’t specify an explicit type for an invocation, the compiler will infer a type from the context.

Since the `main` method invokes the `fail()` method, it can choose a type argument for `R` to make the containing expression applicable to the invocation of `valueOf`. In contrast, `main` declares the `T` type parameter and has no control over it; choosing an actual type argument for `T` is up to `main`’s caller. All `main` can assume, is that it will be assignable to `Object` (as no other bound has been given).

So, the key point is that `T` is a type that `main` can’t convert to a numeric type. Just like with `(Object)fail()` or `Test.<Object>fail()`. The caller could use an actual type for `T` that is convertible to a numeric type but that can’t change the logic within the `main` method.

Instead of casting to `(T)`, you could also just write `Test.<T>fail()` to tell the compiler that you want use `T` for `R`. In either case, you prevent the compiler from inferring a type argument for `R` from the surrounding context.

---

The JLS section linked in your question is not about “Poly expressions in Conditional expressions” but only about the different forms of Conditional expressions and you have to resolve the type of the Poly expression first, before you can determine which kind of Conditional expression you have.

As said, without an explicit type argument and without the type cast, the target type determines the type for `<R>` for the generic invocation of `fail()`. When you invoke `String.valueOf(Object)`, the target type is `Object`, but when you invoke `String.valueOf(char)`, the target type is `char`.

Both works, as you also can write

```java
char c = true? 'a': fail();

Object o = true? 'a': fail();
```

In the second case, `Object` is inferred for `<R>` and the combination of `char` and `Object` from [Table 15.25-E](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25-400-E) applies, which defines the result to be `lub(Character,Object)`. Which is `Object`.

But in the first case, `Character` will be inferred for `<R>`, so the combination of `char` and `Character` from [Table 15.25-C](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25-400-C) applies, defining the result to to be `char`.

Note that this is a [numeric conditional expression](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25-300-B) which allows a variety of type conversions.

We could also write

```java
int i = true? 'a': fail();
```

which promotes the `char` to `int` and infers `Integer` for `fail()`’s `<R>` (though it would also work if `fail()` returned `Character`, `Short`, or `Byte`). So `valueOf(int)` is also applicable here, but since `valueOf(char)` is *more specific*, this does not contribute to the *ambiguous method invocation* error.

So after ruling out all inapplicable and less specific methods, `valueOf(char)` and `valueOf(Object)` remain and neither is more specific, so the compiler error is generated.

When you insert the cast to `T`, which is not convertible to a numeric type, you have a [Reference Conditional Expression](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25.3) whose result is `lub(Character,T)`, which evaluates to `Object`. Then, only `String.valueOf(Object)` is applicable.

Comment: I understand the error. But i still have a small doubt. When i'm casting the return type of `fail()` to `<T>`, the compiler still doesn't know what `T` is. But how is it able to infer `T` to be `Object` or `char` and compile fine?

Comment: It doesn’t. When you cast to `T`, it doesn’t know anything about `T` except that it is assignable to `Object`. That’s why only `valueOf(Object)` can be invoked. The caller of `fail()` can only decide what `R` is. Note that this is a special case. Normally, generic methods have arguments imposing constraints on the type arguments. A no-arg method has no constraints, so the caller can choose whatever they want. E.g. `List<String> l = Collections.emptyList();` or `List<Character> l = Collections.emptyList();`. It only works because the list is always empty. Likewise `fail()` never returns a value

Comment: For a minute there I thought I understood it but man it's hard. But can't we say the same argument about the type represented by `R`? It can also be assumed to be assignable to `Object` and thus resolve to `valueOf(Object)`?? So without a cast to `T`, why can't the compiler infer it to be assignable to Object?

Comment: It can. But since the caller of `fail()` can select any type for `R`, it can also infer `Character` for `R`. In combination with a conditional which has `char` on other branch, it means it can infer `Object` for `R` and box `char` to `Character`, making the entire conditional’s type `Object`, or it can infer `Character` for `R` and unbox it to `char`, so the conditional’s type would be `char`. That’s the problem. There are two valid alternatives and neither has precedence. Recall the roles; `main` is the caller of `fail()` and can *select* a type for `R` but the declared `T` is an unknown type

Comment: Sir, You nailed it Now! I wish i can upvote your answer again. Could you consider adding this comment to the answer as well?